# r, update the timestamp based on following record's value

Tags: r, timestamp

Trying to manipulate the timestamp variable in such a way: if the start time of the following activity is before the end time of the previous activity, then update the start and end time of the previous activity as 1 second before the following activity.

Additional notes:

An activity can be repeated within the same work; i.e. the activity "A".

Some individual activities have the same start and end times some different. This is something I've done intentionally; you can ignore this.

```
workID  workActivityID activity     status             timestamp      timestampDesired
     1               1        A      start   2018-01-01 09:55:01   2018-01-01 09:54:05
     1               1        A        end   2018-01-01 09:55:01   2018-01-01 09:54:05
     1               2        B      start   2018-01-01 09:54:06   2018-01-01 09:54:06
     1               2        B        end   2018-01-01 09:56:22   2018-01-01 09:56:22
     1               3        C      start   2018-01-01 09:57:22   2018-01-01 09:57:22
     1               3        C        end   2018-01-01 09:57:22   2018-01-01 09:57:22
     1               4        A      start   2018-02-02 08:35:00   2018-02-02 08:35:00
     1               4        A        end   2018-02-02 08:35:00   2018-02-02 08:35:00
     2               1        A      start   2018-02-02 08:13:55   2018-02-02 08:14:01
     2               1        A        end   2018-02-02 08:14:20   2018-02-02 08:14:01
     2               2        B      start   2018-02-02 08:14:02   2018-02-02 08:14:02
     2               2        B        end   2018-02-02 08:14:50   2018-02-02 08:14:50
     2               3        C      start   2018-02-02 10:00:00   2018-02-02 10:00:00
     2               3        C        end   2018-02-02 10:00:00   2018-02-02 10:00:00
     2               4        A      start   2018-02-02 10:22:00   2018-02-02 10:22:00
     2               4        A        end   2018-02-02 10:24:00   2018-02-02 10:24:00
```

Data:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- 
  data.frame(
    workID = rep(c(1,2), each=8),
    workActivityID = rep(c(1,2,3,4), each=2, times=2),
    activity = rep(c("A","B","C","A"), each=2, times=2),
    startEnd = rep(c("start", "end"), times=8),
    timestamp = ymd_hms(c("2018-01-01 09:55:01", "2018-01-01 09:55:01", "2018-01-01 09:54:06", "2018-01-01 09:56:22", "2018-01-01 09:57:22", "2018-01-01 09:57:22", "2018-02-02 08:35:00","2018-02-02 08:35:00",
                          "2018-02-02 08:13:55", "2018-02-02 08:14:20", "2018-02-02 08:14:02", "2018-02-02 08:14:50", "2018-02-02 10:00:00", "2018-02-02 10:00:00", "2018-02-02 10:22:00", "2018-02-02 10:24:00")),
    timestampDesired = ymd_hms(c("2018-01-01 09:54:05", "2018-01-01 09:54:05", "2018-01-01 09:54:06", "2018-01-01 09:56:22", "2018-01-01 09:57:22", "2018-01-01 09:57:22", "2018-02-02 08:35:00", "2018-02-02 08:35:00",
                                 "2018-02-02 08:14:01", "2018-02-02 08:14:01", "2018-02-02 08:14:02", "2018-02-02 08:14:50", "2018-02-02 10:00:00", "2018-02-02 10:00:00", "2018-02-02 10:22:00", "2018-02-02 10:24:00")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution can be reached using `tidyr::spread`, `tidyr::gather`.  The approach is simple in the sense that move `start` and `end` in same row so that decision and change operation (if needed) will be easier. Once modification is performed change it back to long format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% select(-timestampDesired) %>%
  spread(startEnd, timestamp) %>%
  group_by(workID) %>%
  mutate(start = as.POSIXct(ifelse(!is.na(lead(start)) & lead(start) < end,
                  lead(start) - 1, start), origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00" )) %>%
  mutate(end = as.POSIXct(ifelse(!is.na(lead(start)) & lead(start) < end,
                 lead(start)  - 1, end), origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00" )) %>%
  ungroup() %>%  
  gather("startEnd", "timestamp", c("start","end")) %>%
  arrange(workID, workActivityID, desc(startEnd)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#      workID workActivityID activity startEnd           timestamp
# 1       1              1        A    start 2018-01-01 09:54:05
# 2       1              1        A      end 2018-01-01 09:54:05
# 3       1              2        B    start 2018-01-01 09:54:06
# 4       1              2        B      end 2018-01-01 09:56:22
# 5       1              3        C    start 2018-01-01 09:57:22
# 6       1              3        C      end 2018-01-01 09:57:22
# 7       1              4        A    start 2018-02-02 08:35:00
# 8       1              4        A      end 2018-02-02 08:35:00
# 9       2              1        A    start 2018-02-02 08:14:01
# 10      2              1        A      end 2018-02-02 08:14:01
# 11      2              2        B    start 2018-02-02 08:14:02
# 12      2              2        B      end 2018-02-02 08:14:50
# 13      2              3        C    start 2018-02-02 10:00:00
# 14      2              3        C      end 2018-02-02 10:00:00
# 15      2              4        A    start 2018-02-02 10:22:00
# 16      2              4        A      end 2018-02-02 10:24:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works well ! I appreciate if you can briefly explain the logic of  that part: as.POSIXct(ifelse(!is.na(lead(start)) & lead(start) < end, lead(start) - 1, start), origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00" )

Comment: It check the `end` time of current row with `start` time of next row. If start time is less 1 second is subtracted. `lead` gives you data from next row. Finally after operation time changed to double format. I had to change It back to POSIXct format.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting a data.table solution. Explanation inline

```
#cast into a wide format
wideDT <- dcast.data.table(DT, ... ~ startEnd, value.var="timestamp")

#lead the start time vector and compare start time and amend start and end time if required
wideDT[, c("newstart", "newend") := {
        x <- shift(start, type="lead", fill=max(end))
        list(newstart=as.POSIXct(ifelse(x < end, x - 1, start), origin="1970-01-01"),
            newend=as.POSIXct(ifelse(x < end, x - 1, end), origin="1970-01-01"))
    }, by=.(workID)]

#get OP's desired output
wideDT[.(workID, workActivityID, activity), 
    list(startend=c("start", "end"), 
        timestamp=c(start, end),
        timestampDesired=c(newstart, newend)), by=.EACHI]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
    workID = rep(c(1,2), each=8),
    workActivityID = rep(c(1,2,3,4), each=2, times=2),
    activity = rep(c("A","B","C","A"), each=2, times=2),
    startEnd = rep(c("start", "end"), times=8),
    timestamp = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 09:55:01", "2018-01-01 09:55:01", "2018-01-01 09:54:06", "2018-01-01 09:56:22", "2018-01-01 09:57:22", "2018-01-01 09:57:22", "2018-02-02 08:35:00","2018-02-02 08:35:00",
        "2018-02-02 08:13:55", "2018-02-02 08:14:20", "2018-02-02 08:14:02", "2018-02-02 08:14:50", "2018-02-02 10:00:00", "2018-02-02 10:00:00", "2018-02-02 10:22:00", "2018-02-02 10:24:00")))
```

Comment: Thank you as well! This will be useful with larger tables.

Comment: In original dataset, there are 15 columns. Instead of individually writing the column names as .(workID, workActivityID, activity), can we include them automatically?

Comment: Yes, you can use DT[,-c(“start”,”end”,”newstart”,”newend”)] instead of .(blah blah blah). Not in front of computer